# What is the SQL to change the field length of a table column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the SQL to make a field go from `nvarchar(50)` to `nvarchar(250)`?

When I try to change it through the SQL Server Management Studio, it doesn't allow me to do it, so I figured I would try SQL directly instead of using the GUI.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
Alter table tblname ALTER Column colname nvarchar(250) [NOT] NULL
```

If `NULL` / `NOT NULL` is not specified the column will become Nullable irrespective of what ever the original specification was.

Comment: @Joe. The square brackets indicate that part of the syntax is optional. It is the Backus–Naur format used in books online. Just indicates remove the `NOT` if that's not the desired semantics or leave it in if it is.

Comment: Yes, understood - oops... :)

Answer (score 11):

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable
ALTER COLUMN MyColumn varchar(NewSize)
```

Answer (score 8):

**The ALTER TABLE Statement**

The ALTER TABLE statement is used to add, delete, or modify columns in an existing table.
**SQL ALTER TABLE Syntax**

**To add a column in a table, use the following syntax:**

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD column_name datatype
```

To delete a column in a table, use the following syntax (notice that some database systems don't allow deleting a column):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
DROP COLUMN column_name
```

To change the data type of a column in a table, use the following syntax:

**SQL Server / MS Access:**

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN column_name datatype
```

**My SQL / Oracle (prior version 10G):**

ALTER TABLE table_name
MODIFY COLUMN column_name datatype

**Oracle 10G and later:**

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
MODIFY column_name datatype
```

Answer (score 2):

Its sometimes safer to check if the table exist in the first place...

```
IF COL_LENGTH('[tablename]','[tablecolumn]') IS NULL
        BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE tablename
            ALTER COLUMN [tablecolumn] 
            NVARCHAR(500)  
        END
```

Answer (score 0):

### To change the datatype of many column but same datatype

```
alter table employee modify (firstname varchar2(9),lastname varchar2(9),email varchar2(9));
-- Table altered.


alter table employee modify (firstname,lastname,email varchar2(9));
-- Table altered.
```

Comment: The question is asking for a SQL statement in SQL Server (i.e. T-SQL), and your answer does not T-SQL.

Answer (score -1):

For Oracle SQL Developers

```
Alter table tblname MODIFY (colname varchar2(250));
```

> Description : It will increase the length of column. where 250
>   represent the updated (incremented) length of column.

Comment: Yes, [this has already been stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29412193/542251). Also this is tagged [tag:SQL-Server]