# How to change the column length of a primary key in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key

I know how to change the length of a column, but my SQL statement fails because the column I'm trying to change is a PK, so I get the following error:

> Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The object 'PK_TableName' is dependent on column 'PersonID'.

PersonID = PK.

I've read [What is the sql to change the field length of a table column in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372176/what-is-the-sql-to-change-the-field-length-of-a-table-column-in-sql-server) which only applies to non-PK columns.

I tried this:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN column_name <new datatype>
```

Comment: P.S. I do not want to drop/re-create the table because the table contains millions of rows...

Comment: I don't think you have a choice...

Comment: you won't need to drop the table, but you will need to drop the pk constraint before changing the column (and potentially drop any referencing FK constraints) which you can recreate afterwards

Comment: Did you specify `NOT NULL`? Are you making the column bigger (going from varchar(6) to varchar(8)) or smaller (vice versa)? Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118568/alter-column-datatype-with-primary-key?rq=1

Comment: I'm in agreement with NDJ, as far as I'm aware you will need to drop the PK constraint, modify and then reapply the constraint.

Comment: @TTeeple , yes I did specify no null

Answer (score 34, accepted):

See below sample example how to increase size of the primary column

1. Create a sample table

   `create table abc (id varchar(10)  primary key)`
2. Find primary constraint in key constraints tables

   `select object_name(object_id),* from sys.key_constraints where object_name(parent_object_id) = 'abc`
3. Drop constraint

   `ALTER TABLE abc
   DROP CONSTRAINT PK__abc__3213E83F74EAC69B`

   *(Replace PK__abc__3213E83F74EAC69B with constraint name you receive.)*
4. Add not null

   `ALTER TABLE abc alter column id varchar(20) NOT NULL;`
5. Add primary key again

   `ALTER TABLE abc 
    ADD CONSTRAINT MyPrimaryKey PRIMARY KEY (id)`

Comment: THanks for the reply. Not sure why my question was voted down. This way, this question will appear over and over again because negative questions do not show up in searches..

Answer (score 5):

```
ALTER TABLE <Table_Name>
DROP CONSTRAINT <constraint_name>

ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN column_name datatype

ALTER TABLE <Table_Name>
ADD CONSTRAINT <constraint_name> PRIMARY KEY (<Column1>,<Column2>)
```

Comment: THanks for the reply. Not sure why my question was voted down. This way, this question will appear over and over again because negative questions do not show up in searches..

Answer (score 0):

SQLServer 2008 did not allow me to change a primary key with data so I deactivated all the constraints, performed the command and activated all the constraints again. The commands are:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1="ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL"

-- commands here

EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1="ALTER TABLE ? CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL"
```